# FullCalendar eventDrop not working

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

All,
I'm using wordpress with this and for some reason the eventDrop stopped working. All of the other callbacks seem to work. For example, eventResize and eventClick both work without an issue. However when I drag my event and move it to something else it just moves it but nothing comes up. I have the following code for it:

```
eventDrop: function(event,dayDelta,minuteDelta,revertFunc) {
        event_id = event.id;
        change_days = dayDelta;
        change_minutes = minuteDelta;
        jQuery.post("http://www.website.com/update_calendar_event.php", { event_id: event_id, change_days: change_days, change_minutes: change_minutes, type: "event_drop" },
            function(data){
                //alert(data);
            });
        if (!confirm("is this okay?")) {
            revertFunc();
        }
    },
```

When I test this on my localhost it works though. Any ideas on why this wouldn't work or have any ideas on how to fix it?

**EDIT** I figured this out, for some reason it isn't working with jQuery 1.7.1. When I was testing this out I was testing with 1.5.2.

What change do I have to make to allow this to work with 1.7.1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, there is an issue already logged. If you just edit the fullcalendar.js file the problem will be fixed. Here is a link to the solution:

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1208

Answer (score 0):

Yes this issue is already fixed with the latest version of the fullcalendar:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/

Greetings